# How to get permission for file access

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions

Code:

```
$file= '../LOGS/'.$time.'.csv';
chmod("../LOGS/", 777);
$fp = fopen($file, 'c+');
```

I get warning: "operation not permitted".

How to get permission. Please Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the user that is executing the script (most likely `www-data` or `httpd` or whatever is the user for the web server process) does not have access to change the permissions on a file.

To obtain this access, you would need to talk to the system administrator in order to configure the server properly to allow access to the files that are saved by your scripts.

Finally - `777` is always the *wrong* permission mask for your files. You are basically creating a lovely security open door with fresh flowers, a welcome mat and milk and cookies if you set such liberal permissions on files on a web accessible server.

Comment: Don't forget the option that `../LOGS/` does not exist from the cwd of the script - that will also give the same error.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid by manual only we can able to get access permission ah

Comment: There are many ways to set the default permissions for newly created files in a system; however this should be something your system administrator/server admin should decide. Just raise the issue with them and let them give you a solution.